# Recalculate subquery on INSERT for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

When I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Acts ( ParentID int, ActID int, Text nvarchar(255) )
---------------------
1 | 1 | "Hello"
1 | 2 | "Hello again"
2 | 1 | "lol"
2 | 2 | "rofl"
```

where ActID is a consecutive number based on the ParentID.
and I need to insert new row for each of a subset of rows like:

```
INSERT INTO Acts
SELECT ParentID, (SELECT MAX(ActID) + 1 FROM Acts), Text FROM Acts WHERE Text LIKE 'Hello%'
```

I got

```
1 | 1 | "Hello"
1 | 2 | "Hello again"
1 | 3 | "Hello"
1 | 3 | "Hello again"
...
```

I want:

```
1 | 1 | "Hello"
1 | 2 | "Hello again"
1 | 3 | "Hello"
1 | 4 | "Hello again"
```

I quickly realised that the Subquery is only evaluated before the INSERTS take place, that's why it always returns the same Max number. Is there a way to insert the Results one by one so that the subquery may update OR to specify that the subquery needs to update after each row?

Comment: you could change the select to make an entry at a time

Comment: Do you mean with "INSERT INTO Act (...) VALUES (...)"? But I need to insert a row for each result of the query.

Comment: Yes, you can use a Cursor and insert row by row with the lastID +1

Comment: Your outer select statement is missing a from clause. Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL and some DML for sample data.

Comment: You can make separate INSERTS for every result, then send them to the database in a transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it will just get the max ActID and adds 1,2,3 in seq to it.

```
INSERT INTO Acts
SELECT ac.ParentID, (SELECT MAX(ac1.ActID) FROM Acts ac1 WHERE ac1.ParentID = ac.ParentID ) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by ac.ParentID order by ac.ParentID), Text 
FROM Acts ac
WHERE ac.Text LIKE 'Hello%'
```

Comment: Yes! ActID it's incremented for each inserted row. Good answer.

Comment: This is brilliant, although it doesn't do exactly what I want as it is right now. I needed to make a few small edits. I needed a WHERE clause in the subquery like `...(SELECT MAX(ActID) FROM Acts WHERE ParentID = outerActs.ParentID)...` to ensure that it only uses the current ParentID's max ActID.

Comment: To ensure that the row number is grouped by the current ParentID, it's also necessary to use `row_number() over (partition by ParentID order by ParentID)` in addition to the `WHERE` clause from my above comment. 
(I'm not sure if I'm allowed to edit the answer in that way, so I just commented it)